# Sending structured form data in an HTTP POST

Tags: python, django, http, graphql

I'm adapting a GraphQL query to a RESTful API. The code handling this is part of a Django app. The idea is to pass the request along to a back-end microserver instead of handling the request in Django. Simplifying a bit, the query's arguments (in GraphQL's query language) are something like:

```
pattern String
address AddressInput
dist Float
distUnit String
```

where `AddressInput` is:

```
lines String[]
city String
district String
division String
country String
postalCode String
```

So the server ends up seeing its arguments as a Python dict, e.g.

```
{
  'dist': 1,
  'distUnit': 'mi',
  'address': {
     'lines': ['123 Main St.'],
     'city': 'Genericville',
     'division': 'IA',
     'country': 'US'
   }
}
```

How do I put that into an HTTP form in an HTTP request? I could do something like:

```
form = QueryDict(mutable=True)
form['dist'] = [1]
form['distUnit'] = ['mi']
form['address.lines'] = ['123 Main St.']
form['address.city'] = ['Genericville']
form['address.division'] = ['IA']
form['address.country'] = ['US']
```

and process it accordingly on the server, but is there a way that's less of a kludge to handle this?

Comment: Why do you want to put it into HTTP form-data? Why not send it as JSON, for example?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. My microserver is in Go, and I was overly focused on using a "standard" solution. Thanks.

Comment: json is the one of the most standard data structure available and go also supports json.

Comment: If one of you would like credit for an answer, feel free to draft one so I can mark this question answered.